# Django GeoIP Error; invalid path type

Tags: python, django, geolocation

After struggling to get GeoIp installed properly for a Django project, I finally appear to have installed it properly via universal geoip with brew.

Unfortunately, when trying it out in the shell, I'm receiving the following error:

```
>>> from django.contrib.gis.utils.geoip import GeoIP
>>> g = GeoIP()
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/utils/geoip.py", line 193, in __init__
raise TypeError('Invalid path type: %s' % type(path).__name__)
```

TypeError: Invalid path type: tuple

I've been trying to properly install GeoIP for about seven hours so any insight into this latest error would be very much appreciated.

Comment: What is your GEOIP_PATH setting set to in settings.py? It seems that it is not a valid str or unicode.

Comment: This is what I have: import os

DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

GEOIP_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'geoip'),

Comment: do you really have a comma after setting GEOIP_PATH? `GEOIP_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'geoip'),`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really have a comma in there, then you are setting GEOIP_PATH to a tuple and not a string, which would explain the error. If this is the case, simply remove the comma:

```
# settings.py

import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
GEOIP_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'geoip')
```

Comment: Oh, your `__file__` probably turned into __file__ in your above comment

Comment: That's exactly right. I haven't figured out how to post formatted code in comments. But the underscore was there. Still can't figure out what the issue is.

Comment: So essentially GEOIP_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_DIR + 'geoip') should work?

Comment: Well, I tried that and got the same error. Sorry for the frustration. Have been trying to get GeoIP to work for nine hours.

Comment: Okay, i closed out the old shell, restarted and it seems to be working. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you. I made same mistake. I have copied the line from other place in settings.py where it was inside the list (STATICFILES_DIRS).